# Django - order by

Tags: django

I need to sort my objects to use it in my template. Now it is something like:

```
sites = Site.objects.all().order_by('-date', '-group')[:10]
```

Result is for example:

1. today group2
2. today group2
3. yesterday group2
4. yesterday group1
5. three days ago group2
6. four days ago group2

I need:

1. today group2
2. yesterday group2
3. three days ago group2
4. four days ago group2
5. today group1
6. yesterday group1

I simply need 10 newest sites ordered by group. 
I would like to use it in my template (two sites in group2 first and 8 with group 2 or 1 next). Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

you should order first by `group` and then by `date`. Although there are several ways to do this.

On models level, you can achieve this with Meta attribute [**`ordering`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering)

On view level, using the query `sites = Site.objects.order_by( '-group','-date')[:10]'`

Yes, `all()` is not needed for this.

On template level, [**`regroup`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag. You needed to use nested for your sample.

Comment: I can't order first by group because I need 10 newest sites (from both groups).

Answer (score 0):

I made it that way. It works as it should.

```
sites = Site.objects.order_by('-date').order_by('-group', '-date')[:10]
```

It wasn't good idea. Below is proper way to achieve my goal:

My view:

```
sites = Site.objects.order_by('-date')[:10]
```

My template:

```
{% for site in sites|dictsortreversed:"group_id" %}
```